# LINQ query on a custom DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

```cs
var query = from row in testDBDataSet.TestTable
                    where !row.Name.Equals("test")
                    select row;
TestDBDataSet.TestTableDataTable tempTable = 
   (TestDBDataSet.TestTableDataTable) query.CopyToDataTable<TestDBDataSet.TestTableRow>();
TestTableTableAdapter.Fill(tempTable);
```

When running this code I get the error **InvalidOperationException was unhandled - The source contains no DataRows.**

There is certainly data there that meets that criteria, what am I doing wrong? I selected a table from the SQL Server 2008 R2 database to be the `DataSource` for a `DataGridView`. I want it to only show certain rows that meet a criteria.

This also happens when I comment out the `where !row.Name.Equals("test")`

Comment: So your query is empty?

Comment: I would start by using SQL Profiler to see what's being run on the server and see if you can determine from there why you aren't getting rows back.

Comment: Is `TestTable` a `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Try not using .Equals in your query, but rather sticking with:

```
where row.Name != "test"
```

Personally, I've had varied problems trying to use Equal with the Where statements.